# copy an object to a handle in systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog

i have one module, **mod1**, which includes one class, **my_test**. Inside **mod1** there is an instance of another module **mod2** and **mod2** includes a class, **my_config**. the "**my_test**" class also includes the **my_config** class.
I want to copy the object of **my_config** class to another handle of this class which is instantiated inside **mod2** module. Below are the code snippets, you can follow. **my_test**, **my_config**, **mod1**, **mod2** are in different files.

```
class my_test;
  my_config cfg_2;     // instance of my_config class
  // here the object is created
  // here i have assigned some values to the properties of my_config class
  ...
endclass : my_test

module mod2;
  my_config cfg_1;     // instance of my_config class
  // mod2 file includes my_config class
  ...
endmodule : mod2

`include "my_test.sv" // included inside the file "mod1"  
module mod1;
  mod2 m2(..);         // module instance of module mod2
  // mod1 file includes my_test class
  m2.cfg_1 = cfg_2;    // cfg_1 is instance of my_config, inside mod2
  // In the above line i am trying to copy the object cfg_2 to the handle cfg_1
  // I AM GETTING ERROR IN THE ABOVE LINE.
  ...
endmodule : mod1
```

Can anyone please help me out. Thanks

Comment: You have syntax error here: `class my_test`, `module mod2`, and `module mod1`. Please add semicolon at the end of each line.

Comment: Also cfg_2 is not declared inside `mod1`.

Comment: i have included "my_test" class in the file "mod1". thats why i didnt declared it. it is declared inside "my_test" class. @e19293001

Comment: And where did you instantiate this 'my_test'?

Comment: do i need to instantiate **my_test** class. I think if i am including this file in the **mod1** file, then it can access the properties of **my_test** class @Tudor

Comment: A class is one thing and an instance of that thing is another one. You have to create an instance of a class to be able to use those properties.

Comment: you mean to say if i'll create an instance of **my_test** class inside **mod1** and will write the code as **m2.cfg_1 = my_test_inst.cfg_2**, then it'll work... @Tudor

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the instance of `my_test` here, but assuming you create it under the name `my_test_inst`, then do the following:

```
module mod1();
  //...

  // you can only add procedural code in initial blocks
  initial
    m2.cfg_1 = my_test_inst.cfg_2

endmodule
```

Comment: my code for the file **mod1** is like below:      include my_test.sv;
module mod1();  
  mod2 m2();  
  my_test t1 = new();  
  initial begin  
    m2.cfg_1 = t1.cfg_2;  
    $display("value is %0d", m1.cfg_1.a);  
  end  
  initial begin  
    $monitor("%0d",m1.cfg_1.a);  
  end  
endmodule  It is showing error that : Illegal assignment